# Express route not being found - 404 error

Tags: html, node.js, apache, express

I am creating a simple contact form and handling the backend with nodejs and express. I implemented my form using the appropriate action ('/contact') and implemented a route in angular. Whenever I submit my form, I get the error:

```
The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.
```

index.js:

```
// POST route from contact form
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: GMAIL_USER,
      pass: GMAIL_PASS
    }
  });
  mailOpts = {
    from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
    to: GMAIL_USER,
    subject: 'New message from contact form at tylerkrys.ca',
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      res.render('contact-failure');
    }
    else {
      res.render('contact-success');
    }
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<form action="/contact" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
            <h2 class="text-center">Contact us</h2>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control is-invalid" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"><small class="form-text text-danger">Please enter a correct email address.</small></div>
            <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" rows="14" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required="required"></textarea></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send </button></div>
        </form>
```

I am running on an APACHE server, using debian 4.9.88. I have looked at other form posts regarding this issue, and have tried to implement the following .htaccess file in my /public_html/ root directory:

```
1 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                                                                                       
2     RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                                                                               
3 RewriteBase /                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]                                                                                                                                                                                
5 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                                                                                                            
6 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                                                                                                            
7 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]                                                                                                                                                                                  
8 </IfModule>`
```

However this did not solve the issue. This is also due to my lack of understanding exactly how routes work (I read the angular documentation but am still having trouble understanding why the /contact path isn't found).

UPDATE: apparently I needed to change the apache config to "AllowOverride All" upon changing my .htaccess file, and I do not get the 404 error anymore, but the actual route is not being triggered still. I just get redirected to my index.html page: "www.SITE.com/contact" Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your form submitted to angular /contact  route, because you doesn't provide domaine, but should submit to node server. To resolve it you should create new virtual host for node app.

Comment: @DenRupp How would I go about doing this? In my httpd config I need to specify a port, however I am not essentially listening on a port in my index.js (or should I?). Can I just choose an arbitrary port? I've seen a lot on proxypass in forms but I cannot get node to handle this request, it keeps getting handled by apache